# How to get the FloatAction button Click Listener in View pager Fragments?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, floating-action-button

I have created tab layout with view pager fragments in one fragment which is placed in one Main activity. now i want to get the click listener of float action button in one specific fragment from the view pager fragments because i couldn't get the float action button viewId and whose click listener in some specific fragment of view pager fragments so how can i get the instance of float action button and their click listener also and which is need to be show at some specific fragments at the view pager fragments.

Please tell me if anybody having idea about on this.

thanks

Comment: put floatingActionButton in frg xml and make simple listener for that

Comment: No i want which is to being as common for all fragments in view pager, and need to be changing different icons for some specific fragments and handling click listener also. how to do in like this scenarios?